# Detecting degenerate triangles with very thin structures

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry

Between the two ears in the following bunny images, there are some degenerate triangles I want to detect. It looks like a volume-less thin slits.

If the question is not clear, please let me know.

[image: 1]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

**Step 1**: For each edge $P_iP_j$, look at the two triangles that share it: $P_iP_jP_k$ and $P_lP_jP_i$.

**Step 2**: Compute the counter-clockwise normal on each of the two triangle:
$$\vec{n}_{ijk} = \frac{\vec{P_iP_j} \times \vec{P_jP_k}}{\|\vec{P_iP_j} \times \vec{P_jP_k}\|} \,\,\, \text{ and }\,\,\, \vec{n}_{lji} = \frac{\vec{P_lP_j} \times \vec{P_jP_i}}{\|\vec{P_lP_j} \times \vec{P_jP_i}\|}$$

**Step 3**: Check the angle between the two normals: $\big(\vec{n}_{ijk} \cdot \vec{n}_{lji}\big) \approx -1$ (e.g. something like $\big(\vec{n}_{ijk} \cdot \vec{n}_{lji}\big) \leq -1 + \varepsilon$) means it is close to being $180^{\circ}$.

**Step 4**: In this case, you can remove the edge  $P_iP_j$ and merge the two vertices $P_K$ and $P_l$: Replace $P_k$ and $P_l$ by the midpoint $P_m$ of the straight segment $P_kP_l$: 
$$P_m = \frac{1}{2}(P_k + P_l)$$

**Step 5**: Connect all remaining vertices, adjacent to the former vertices $P_k$ or $P_l$, to the new vertex $P_m$. Thus, the new triangulation has now three fewer edges and two fewer triangular faces.

Continue to iterate this procedure until there are no edges whose normals have the property $\big(\vec{n}_{ijk} \cdot \vec{n}_{lji}\big) \approx -1$.

Maybe this algorithm will remove the triangles between the bunny's years.